# password generator with logging

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random, logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s')

file_handler = logging.FileHandler('student.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(file_handler)

mylist = ['Aa', 'Bb', 'Cc', 'Dd', 'Ee', 'Ff', 'Gg', 'Hh', 'Ii', 'Jj', 'Kk', 'Ll', 'Mm', 'Nn', 
'Oo', 'Pp', 'Qq', 'Rr', 'Ss', 'Tt', 'Uu', 'Vv', 'Ww', 'Xx', 'Yy', 'Zz', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', 
'9', '0', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '~']

def generatePassword(num):

    password = ''
    for x in range(mylist):
        return password
logging.debug(generatePassword,16)
```

When I execute the code, complier says that x is an unused variable. Is there a way to fix this? Also, is there any error with how I wrote the logging functions?

Comment: Well you are not using the variable `x` and your function always returns `''`. It really depends on what you want to do.

Comment: It is not a *compiler error*, it is simply an IDE inspection telling you that, well, the variable `x` is not used. It doesn't affect your code except for the fact that it is not used... What is your question here?

Comment: And you have a few issues with your code. I guess you meant `logging.debug(generatePassword(16))` to actually call the function... `range` takes a number so I'm guessing you meant `range(len(mylist))`. Lastly there is no point in having a `return` inside a loop like that. You will always have one iteration...

Answer (score 0):

You are currently not using `x` inside your loop, hence the unused variable warning.

Regardless, consider using [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) if you want to allow the password to possibly contain the same character twice or or [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) if you don't:

```
import random

def generate_password(length, unique_chars_ignore_case=False):
    my_list = [
        'Aa', 'Bb', 'Cc', 'Dd', 'Ee', 'Ff', 'Gg', 'Hh', 'Ii', 'Jj', 'Kk', 'Ll',
        'Mm', 'Nn', 'Oo', 'Pp', 'Qq', 'Rr', 'Ss', 'Tt', 'Uu', 'Vv', 'Ww', 'Xx',
        'Yy', 'Zz', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '!', '@',
        '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '~'
    ]
    random_func = random.choices if not unique_chars_ignore_case else random.sample
    return ''.join([
        x if len(x) == 1 else x[random.randint(0, 1)]
        for x in random_func(my_list, k=length)
    ])
```

**Example Usage allows repeats:**

```
>>> generate_password(6)
C9#cs2
```

**Example Usage only unique characters ignore case:**

```
>>> generate_password(6, unique_chars_ignore_case=True))
k*065@
```